# Returning user to referrer in flask in smartest pythonic way

Tags: python, flask

I want to delete something, so I use a post, but then I want to refer the user back to the view - the url is actually different depending user, so I'd like to be able to send back to referrer, but I don't see a smart way of doing it.

Here is my code:

```
@app.route('/delete', methods=['POST'])
def delete():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        _id = request.form.get('_id')
        mongo.db.xxx.remove({'_id': _id})
        return request.referrer
    else:
        return request.referrer
```

What is the canonical elegant way of doing this. Do I have to use session, or is there another way I can use flask to perform this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When rendering the form for the delete view, you can add a hidden form element named `next`:

```
<form ...>
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.path }}">
    ...
</form>
```

Then in your route:

```
...
return redirect(request.form.get('next', '/'))
```

Note: your redirect handling should take care to prevent the next parameter from being an absolute URL to an arbitrary site (see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Open_redirect).